# How to fix "There is already an open DataReader ..."

Tags: c#, npgsql

I am having problems trying to fix this error:

> There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first.

I know what this error means and how I should fix it, but I create a new `NpgsqlCommand` on an existing `NpgsqlConnection` each time and when the previous command is not finished yet, this error occurs.

The command is run as follows:

```
private object RunSelectScalar(NpgsqlCommand cmd) {
    cmd.Connection = connection;     // connection is a connected NpgsqlConnection
    object result = cmd.ExecuteScalar();

    return result;
}

object o = RunSelectScalar(new NpgsqlCommand("SELECT foo FROM bar LIMIT 1"));
```

so, I don't know how I could close it, or use `using`, as I do not assign a `DataReader`.

Comment: Yes, "close it or use `using`" is the answer. It would help if we could see the code where you create (and probably don't close) the previous command. `DbCommand` is `IDisposable`.

Comment: You are executing one command while the previous command is still returning data (ie there is another reader open). A lookup operation perhaps? Either a *separate* connection for your lookup or modify your SQL code to join with the lookup table and avoid the expensive lookups.

Comment: It isn't possible to answer without the code. The SQL statements would help to find a SQL statement that returns everything in a single round-trip

Comment: The problem likely isn't with the code that is posted, but most likely with preceding code executing on the same connection. You need to post this code as well before more concrete advice can be given.

Comment: I updated my question, adding the call and how it is being run

Comment: In general you cannot execute two commands at the same time on one connection. If you are using same connection from multiple threads - don't. If you are reading something from database and in that middle of that read you need to get additional information from database - use separate connection for that. Connections are pooled, so don't worry too much about perfomance of opening new connection.

Comment: @Evk, I am afraid it is a threading issue yes.....

Comment: Well then either use something like ThreadLocal to use separate conneciton per thread, or (better) - "open" new connection for each logical operation you want to perform (and of course "close" it at the end of operation). It rarely be really opened, because connections are pooled and so most often connection will be just grabbed from pool without any perfomance penalty.

Comment: The issue was caused by using the same `NpgsqlConnection` in two threads. I fixed this and it works fine now. Sorry I wasn't clearer in my question, but apparently I needed some new ideas to find and fix it. Thanks a lot all and happy new year!

Answer (score 0):

Add

> Preload Reader = true;

with your connection string. Worked for me.

For example:

```
 <add name="dbTestConnectionString" connectionString="Server=localhost;Database=dbNew3;User Id=postgres;Password=your_pass;Preload Reader = true;" providerName="Npgsql" />
```